# Connect to IIS server

Tags: windows, iis-7, webserver

I have IIS server on virtual machine. when I connect to it from local LAN I got

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

and when I try to connect from WAN, I got

```
This webpage can't be displayed
```

what should I do to solve this?